# Eclipse Juno : TestNG installed but inaccessible

Tags: eclipse-plugin, installation, testng

I need to use testNG for a studies' project, so I tried to install the ecplipse plugin by two ways: first using a distribution package (I'm using Eclipse Juno on Archlinux) https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/eclipse-testng/ and the second time using the eclipse add-ons installer ("help">"install new softwares...") following these steps : http://selftechy.com/2012/01/09/setting-up-testng-with-eclipse

But, each time, I've this problem : The plug-in seems correctly installed but I do not find it in the menus, like it'd be disabled... for example, I can't see its window in
"Window">"Show view">"Other...">"java".
However, when I go to 
"Help">"About Eclipse SDK">"Installation Details...">"Installed Software",
I see it well : "TestNG 6.8.0.20121120_1820 org.testng.eclipse.feature.group    Cedric Beust"

So what's happening??

Comment: Have you got the answer? As I am also facing the same issue, if yes then please share. thanks

Comment: no, if I had, as you pointed, I would have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you've installed the plugin simply right click on your class file -> Run As -> TestNG Test

Make sure your test methods are properly annotated, i.e.

```
public class Test {

   @Test
   public void test1(){
      System.out.println("test1");   
   } 

   @Test
   public void test2(){
      System.out.println("test2");
   }
}
```